# Search limit / slow default search?

Tags: python, postgresql, search, odoo

There is this method:

```
 def name_search(self, cr, uid, name, args=None, operator='ilike', context=None, limit=100):
        if args is None:
            args = []
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        ids = []
        if name:
            ids = self.search(cr, uid, [('name', operator, name)] + args, limit=limit)
        if not ids:
            ids = self.search(cr, uid, [('city_id', operator, name)] + args, limit=limit)
        if not ids:
            ids = self.search(cr, uid, [('street_id', operator, name)] + args, limit=limit)        
        return self.name_get(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
```

It finds what you want, but for some reason it searches very slowly when no search term is provided (**note**. It wouldn't be strange if it would return all records, but it still returns max 160 records).

There are few problems with this. First it has a limist search of 160 records for some reason even if you looked in method, it shows 100. And If I change to any number it still returns max records of 160 records. Looks like that parameter does not override default 160.

Now the other problem is that when I enter any phrase in search line, it finds results quite quickly, does not matter how many results it finds, because it limits to 160. That would be ok. But if I do not provide any phrase to search for and press little triangle (arrow) in openerp interface (look below for screenshot)

[image]

And the same thing happens when I delete search phrase in `address completion` field. It then also defaults to default search, which finds first 160 records ordered by zip (postal code) column order. For some reason this way it searches much slower. I only noticed this slow performance when I imported addresses (now there are more than 400k rows).

Does anyone know how could I improve this so called default search or at least limit return records so it might increase performance? (as I said for some reason changing `limit=` to some other number does not do anything).

**Simple examples to understand problem:**

1st example:

I write phrase `City1` in `address completion` field. It finds first 160 records that has `City1`. Search is fast.

2nd example:

I don't write anyting in `address completion` field, but instead I press little arrow (the one in screenshot), to open detailed search. It finds first 160 records by postal code order. Search is slow.

3rd example:

I delete written phrase `City1` (after I written it) from `address completion` field. It finds same records as in 2nd example. Search is slow.

**P.S** if anyone needs info about standard OpenERP parameters in ORM methods (like the one I provided): https://doc.openerp.com/6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/methods/

Comment: I guess the main problem was, it tried to order rows by `name/postal code` every time that search was called. And when there are so many rows, it does it slowly. When I removed ordering, speed improved by a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing order rows are returned (it was ordered by postal code), improved speed significantly. I guess if no one knows any better suggestion, this should be a good solution.

To be more specific in code there was this line:

`_order = 'name' #name field is for postal code.`

I deleted it.